# chokidar errors caused images to stop rendering in React with require()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, chokidar

So earlier upon trying to start the development server to view my React app I started receiving multiple errors from **chokidar** and **webpack** about system limit of file watchers, which I managed to "fix" with

`echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl --system` (ArchLinux system)

as well as having the node_modules folder of the project be ignored by the watcher, like so:

**webpack.config.js**

```
watchOptions: {
  ignored: /node_modules/
}
```

Doing this allowed me to run the project again but in the process some images that I dynamically import (they are located in the images subfolder inside **src**, **NOT** **public**) no longer render (broken icon displays instead).

This is how I display the images:

**Members.js**

```
const Members = [
{
    value: 1,
    color: "yellow",
    name: "AmorAltra",
    role: "Event Host",
    image: require("../../images/skins/amoraltra.png"),
    icon: require("../../images/icons/Amor.png"),
    description: "Hi, Amor here!"
},... 
export default Members
```

This array of JSON objects is then imported into

**Team.js**

```
import Members from "./Members";
```

Subsequently I create an array of img tags for those images...

```
const renderList = [];

for(let i=0; i<=19; i++) {
    renderList.push(
        <img key={Members[i].value} src={Members[i].icon} alt={Members[i].name} className="icon" />
    )
}
```

and display them inside a div element within the return() function of the Component...

```
return(<div className="select">{renderList}</div>)
```

This worked perfectly until the errors from chokidar and webpack appeared. One thing I tried doing was refactoring the linking of the images to be loaded from the public folder rather than src, but React would simply be unable to resolve the filename or would return

> You attempted to import ../../public/images...

I'm so confused as to what's the issue here is, especially being new to React overall... Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: to clarify: [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvDy8.png) is folder structure of the project.

Comment: as you're new to react, why are you even worrying about web pack? and why do you need chokidar?

Comment: I'm assuming they're included in create-react-app. It's not like I installed them myself.

Comment: There is probably something broken in you react app. Using create-react-app, at the beginning weback should not be something you should have to worry about at all, it works out of the box. Try creating a new app with create react app.

Comment: tried, didn't work